# How to remove spaces from an entire Excel column using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete the spaces that I have in each field of the column "A" this spaces are at the end of the string some of the string has 3 spaces others 4. When I run the code, I don't have error, so I think I have a bug because nothing happened when is running.

```
Dim result As String
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
      If (Right(Cells(i, "A").Value, 4)) Like "    " Or (Right(Cells(i, "A").Value, 3)) Like "   " Then
        result = Replace(Cells(i, "A"), " ", "")
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently you are not actually updating the cell in the loop, you just;

```
result = Replace(Cells(i, "A"), " ", "")
```

You should:

```
Cells(i, "A") = Replace(Cells(i, "A"), " ", "")
```

Or better

```
Cells(i, "A") = rtrim$(Cells(i, "A"))
```

Which will remove all right spaces.  You can probably remove the if check as well.

Comment: The $ at the end is **really** *old school* ! Does it have an added value ?

Comment: Yes; its the version of the function that actually returns a string, without it you get an unnecessary variant

Answer (score 12):

In your specific case, the problem is that you're storing the replacement value in a string variable named `result`, then doing nothing with it. If you want it to be in the `Cell`, you have to add it back in there, such as:

`Cells(I, "A").Value = result`

Keep in mind, there is an `Application.Trim` method that can actually save a bit of time over looping. Experiment with code such as:

```
Dim rng as Range

set rng = Range("A1:A10")
rng.Value = Application.Trim(rng)
```

Comment: `Trim`ming a range does not work. You have to Trim cell by cell

Comment: @iDevlop Give it a try. Using `Application.Trim` (as opposed to the WorksheetFunction or just `Trim`) allows you to trim a range.

Comment: Well. I **did** try and got an error, before posting. But now I realize that it was because I copied your code which has an error on line 3: `)"` instead of `")`. So edit your code so I can change the downvote into an upvote ;-)

Comment: @iDevlop Whoops, and thanks for the heads up! I occasionally type code responses directly into the website (without testing) for easier blocks of code, and I missed that.

Comment: This is a nice piece of useful VBA. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What are expecting this code to do? as currently the values are being read into result. It would also be better to use trim to remove trailing spaces.

```
Dim result As String
Last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        result = RTrim(Cells(i, "A"))
    Next i
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your quick response