# Removing spaces from cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove all spaces from cells in a specific column. I found this question,which has an answer:[How to remove spaces from an entire Excel column using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013844/how-to-remove-spaces-from-an-entire-excel-column-using-vba)

This is how I adapted the answer:

```
For i = 2 To n
    Cells(i, 17).Value = Replace(Cells(i, 17).Value, " ", "")
Next i
```

It does eliminate the space but it also eliminates a comma. For example "424, 426" changes to "424426".

I did run my code one part at a time to make sure that the problem indeed happens in that specific cope block.

How should I change the code to make sure that only the spaces get eliminated?

Comment: Most likely because the cell is formatted a number. Try changing the format the "General" **before** running the macro.

Comment: @A.S.H The cells are formatted as "general. Would that be an issue?

Comment: Change the formatting of the column to `Text` and not `General` or use the method that I gave in the post below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to remove the leading and trailing space. For that you do not need to loop. Here is a one liner example

```
Sub Sample()
    [A1:A20] = [INDEX(TRIM(A1:A20),)]
End Sub
```

For explanation see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells/19986324#19986324) post

[image]

**Edit**

To remove all spaces, change your code to

```
For i = 2 To n
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, 17).Value, ",") Then
        Cells(i, 17).Value = Replace("'" & Cells(i, 17).Value, " ", "")
    Else
        Cells(i, 17).Value = Replace(Cells(i, 17).Value, " ", "")
    End If
Next i
```

or change the formatting of the entire column to `Text` before you do the replace.

[image]

Comment: Working with a whole range at once like this is certainly much faster than a cell loop.

Comment: But using Trim doesn't remove spaces in middle of the string, which is what I need too (see the example I provided).

Comment: @Alluton: It does remove :) . Type "aaaaaaa            aaaaaa" in cell A1 where there is lot of space between 2 words and try my code

Comment: @Alluton: See the screenshot attached. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: Doesn't that screenshot show that there is still one space left in between "dsasd" and "sadasd" ?

Comment: You want to remove those as well? @Alluton

Comment: Yes. I don't want to have any spaces left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146736/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-alluton).