# How to show difference between 2 tables ingoring extra spaces?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I've got power query to show difference between tables A B, sometimes in one of them is extra space but inside is excatly the same but showing this is not equal and appear in my new table, could someone help me how to add function to ignore spaces

```
let
Source = Table.NestedJoin( Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], {"CU_PIRD", "Text"}, Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content], {"CU_PIRD", "Text"}, "Source", JoinKind.LeftAnti)
```

in
Source

for example table A:

```
Hello World
```

Table B:

```
Hello   World
```

Contain same text with extra space, i want to void cases like this

Comment: [How to remove spaces from an entire Excel column using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013844/how-to-remove-spaces-from-an-entire-excel-column-using-vba) it is not what you asked, but it will result in the same..

Comment: This not solve my problem, i dont want to remove anything. After compare 2 rows between 2 tables dont want to see row as difference , but both rows need to stay origin

Comment: Before doing your `Join`, you'll have to replicate Excel's TRIM function and apply it to both tables.