# VBA Excel TRIM function for all columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba

Since I know, how to manage tih the TRIM function ddon to the last row, as advised here:

[How to remove spaces from an entire Excel column using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013844/how-to-remove-spaces-from-an-entire-excel-column-using-vba/32013896)

or here:

[Trim Cells using VBA in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964769/trim-cells-using-vba-in-excel)

I want to do the same down to the last column.

In this case I prepared the following code:

```
  Sub trimit()
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, lCol As Long

 Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  With wks
     lRow = .Columns("B:K").End(xlDown).Row
     lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     For i = 1 To lRow
         .Cells(i, lCol).Value = trim(.Cells(i, lCol).Value)
     Next i
 End With
  End Sub
```

There is no error, but the code results from[image] no reaction, or at most changes in column B only.

How can I apply the same for all the columns down to the last one?

Comment: Why don't you trim a whole [range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454080/9758194) at once instead of a loop?

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: The answer is literally there in the link i enclosed.